# JMeter JDBC Call returns the value as parameter name if the value received from DB is null

Tags: jmeter

I am using a JDBC PreProcessor in JMeter to fetch a value from the DB before firing a SOAP call which needs to be enriched with that information.

I have assigned a variable `XYZ` to fetch the value returned from DB.
If there is a value returned from DB, i am able to get that value using `${XYZ_1}` successfully, however if the value returned from DB is nothing  `(null)` (as seen in DB), the value returned using `${XYZ_1}` is shown as `${XYZ_1}`.

I am using this variable in Sampler as 
`<Location>${XYZ_1}</Location>`

Ex: If DB returns value as 'California', i get it as `<Location>California</Location>`

If DB returns value as nothing (null), the value looks like 
`<Location>${XYZ_1}</Location>`.

Now my issue here is, if DB returns the value as nothing (null), i want the value to be set as nothing. So it should like like below

`<Location></Location>`

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your SQL so that instead of null it returns empty.

Another option is to put a JSR223 Post Processor  + Groovy (or Beanshell Post Processor) after your JDBC Post Processor that would test the variable and if null put empty String instead.

Comment: yes.. thanks.. i have used decode function in the SQL statement and modified the expected output. Now i am getting the response as `<Location> </Location>` (with a space) instead of `<Location></Location>`

Comment: It is not what i wanted to achieve. But yes, it did resolve the issue for now. I did not have enough reputation to up vote earlier.. did it now :)